# How to do Python insertion sort on certain range of the list only?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

So, I tried and get [1, 2, 3, 5, -4] but I want to get [3, 1, 2, 5, -4] as result instead; because I want to sort only from index 1 to index 4 (including start, excluding end; which mean only sorting from index 1 to index 3, leaving index 0 and 4 as it is) of the list

```
def insertionSort(the_list, start, end):
    for mark in range(start, end):
        temp = the_list[mark]
        i = mark-1
        while i >= 0 and the_list[i] > temp:
            the_list[i+1] = the_list[i]
            i -= 1
        the_list[i+1] = temp

    return the_list

print(insertionSort([3, 2, 5, 1, -4], 1, 4))
```

Can someone help me fix the code so I can get the result I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice the section you want to sort. Here's how I would implement.

```
def insertionSort(alist,s, e):

    #check if s or e is greater than the length of the list
    if s >= len(alist) or e >= len(alist):
        #if True, then request is invalid
        return ('invalid request')

    #sort the list for the slice of data
    alist[s:e] = sorted(alist[s:e])

    # now return the full list 
    # The above code ensures you are not touching values before and after
    return alist

print (insertionSort([3, 2, 5, 1, -4], 1, 4))
```

The output of this will be:

```
[3, 1, 2, 5, -4]
```

Explanation of issues in your code:

Your for loop starts from start to end. However, you are checking for values from start - 1 (code i = mark - 1). When mark is 1 (start), you are setting i to 0 (mark - 1 i.e., 1 - 1 = 0). That makes your code consider 0th position. That's why you are getting `1, 2, 3, 5, -4` as the output.

Also, if you give a value greater than the number of elements in the list, your code will crash. You have to take care of that condition as well. For example, if you give `print (insertionSort([3, 2, 5, 1, -4], 1, 7))`, the code will crash.